# How to get the “shareable link” of a Google Drive file inside a folder via Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have google drive folder, inside folder there is multiple files. i want to generate the shareable file links using the folder name. i tried following script but getting error.

````
  var Foldername = "foldername";
  var files = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(Foldername).getFiles();
  var result = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
      var temp = {
        file_name: file.getName(),
        url: "http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + file.getId(),
      };
      result.push(temp);
  };
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result))
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shareable links are the same you can get with [getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#geturl). In your case:

```
var temp = {
  file_name: file.getName(),
  url: file.getUrl()
};
```